# How to create resize event for TLabel (TGraphicControl)

Tags: delphi, winapi, resize, notifications, tlabel

I'm trying to create TLabel descendant, which will display hint with the whole caption when the text width exceed label width. I've set the EllipsisPosition property to epEndEllipsis and my caption is automatically shorted by an ellipsis at the end. That's fine.

However **I need to be notified, that the text has been shortened to set up the hint**. This in my case may happen only when the text is changed (message CM_TEXTCHANGED) and when the component is resized.

And that's my question - **how can I be notified, that my TLabel has been resized ?** I have the anchors there, so it's resized along with the form, but I would like to wrap it in the separate TLabel descendant.

**This code works, but isn't there a better way ? Something like WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, but working for TGraphicControl ?**

```
procedure TEllipsisLabel.WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged);
begin
  inherited;

  if Assigned(Parent) then
    if Canvas.TextWidth(Caption) > Width then
      begin
        ShowHint := True;
        Hint := Caption;
      end
    else
      begin
        ShowHint := False;
        Hint := '';
      end;
end;
```

**Thanks a lot :)**

Comment: Can override `SetBounds`, which is where `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` is performed. Or if you wish to put the code in an event handler, you can simply publish the `OnResize` property of your descendant. Don't see any reason why either one would be better than a message handler though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to be notified that the `TLabel` descendant has been resized.  **Instead, you want to be notified that it has shortened the text**.  I know they seem the same, but they're not - the label might still be wider than the text, it might have `WordWrap` turned on, etc.  In addition, `TCustomLabel` descendants can use a couple of different methods to draw text, based on theming / Vista / Aero glow stuff (they boil down to [`DrawThemeTextEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773317%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901121.aspx)), so you need to hook into that system to know exactly what the text it's drawing is doing, including what the size of the rendered text is.

If you're using a non-Starter edition of Delphi, have a look at the `TCustomLabel` source in `stdctrls.pas`.  There are two methods of interest:

- `TCustomLabel.AdjustBounds` - this is where the bounding rectangle is set, and it adjusts for word wrapping etc.  It does this by calling (as does painting) the other method of interest:
- `TCustomLabel.DoDrawText` - this paints the text and/or calculates the text bounding rectangle accounting for ellipses, wrapping, that kind of thing.  **Internally, it generates an altered string that is the text that is actually painted.**  In other words, this method's functionality is what tells you whether the text fits or not.

Both are `dynamic`, which is semantically equivalent to being `virtual` - ie, you can override them.

`DoDrawText` unfortunately doesn't return the final text string it's painting - if it did, you could override it, call the inherited version and compare the painted text with the real text.  However, you can override and reimplement it, and do this yourself.  Use the VCL code as a guide (you want equivalent functionality, although you should not copy it directly since it's owned by Embarcadero.)  Being `dynamic`, your descendant class's version will be called by `AdjustBounds`.  In your code, when you shorten the text, also set a flag it's been shortened or generate the hint immediately.  Voila.  You accurately know exactly when it's been shortened :)

Comment: Yes exactly, I need to be notified when my TLabel is shortened by the epEndEllipsis three dot string, but how to do it ?

Comment: The last paragraph of my answer should explain that (specifically, "override and reimplement it... when you shorten the text, also set a flag it's been shortened or...").  What in it don't you understand / can I expand for you?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of anything better than `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`:

> Sent to a window whose size, position,
>   or place in the Z order has changed as
>   a result of a call to the SetWindowPos
>   function or another window-management
>   function.

That looks ideal. What do you have against using it?

Comment: The fact, that it's called too early (before parent is known) and I need to carry of the parent assignment else I get the access violation, so I was asking for some specific message or method which doesn't need this check and which is called only for size change.

Comment: Can't you only do the work that needs Parent assigned when Parent is assigned?

Comment: Yep, but I hoped there's something like WM_EXITSIZEMOVE what might be called just once when the control has finished its sizing.

Comment: Doesn't he really want to check when the text is shortened, not when the label's resized?  Resizing may not change the displayed text at all.

Comment: @David M - yes he does :) but how would you do this ? I want to display hint with the whole caption when the text is shortened, that's all

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override the **AdjustBounds** method.  Try the following code (simply create a form with a **TButton** and **TLabel** on it and replace the **.pas** with this code).  This example demonstrates detecting a label size change if the text changes.  You will need to create your own event though.

```
unit unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TSizeNotifyLabel = class(TLabel)
  public
    procedure AdjustBounds; override;

end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }

    SizeNotifyLabel: TSizeNotifyLabel;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation


procedure TSizeNotifyLabel.AdjustBounds;
begin
  inherited;
  form1.label1.caption := 'Width of Label:'+inttostr(form1.SizeNotifyLabel.Width);
end;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SizeNotifyLabel.Caption := SizeNotifyLabel.Caption + ' Change My Size';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

begin
  SizeNotifyLabel := TSizeNotifyLabel.Create(self);
  with SizeNotifyLabel do begin
    caption := 'Hello World';
    left := 10;
    top := 10;
    autosize := true;
    parent := self;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Comment: I don't think OP is using AutoSize. If so then why would the ellipsis be needed?

Comment: @David - you're right, but anyway AdjustBounds may be the solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override `Resize` method. However, be aware that your code

```
if Canvas.TextWidth(Caption) > Width then
```

is different from how `TCustomLabel.DoDrawText` determines when to draw ellipses so you may get unexpected results.

Also, the ellipses drawing may also be caused by a font change, a theme setting change, and maybe some other events.

Comment: I agree with you, but in my case it's enough to calculate width in this way, because fonts are theme independent (I hope :) and there are no frames on the label. And the mentioned Resize method looks good for me - I'll check it as soon as possible. And font change I've had in my mind, but this will never happen, for me is important only text change and resize :)